# "redefinition different basic types" problem with my flush function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, flush

at the top of my program i wrote this line of code

```
#define FLUSH myFlush()
```

then, i later wrote out the myFlush function as follows.

```
void myFlush() {
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

This way whenever i need to flush, i just type FLUSH; and it does it. like so

```
scanf("%i", voters[i].favoriteNumber); FLUSH;
```

The problem is, i'm getting an error at the line of myFlush function. The error is "redefinition different basic types." C2371. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That macro definition saves you four characters. It's not worth it. Don't obfuscate your code to save a tiny amount of typing.